# What is in the Windows 8 "shared core?"

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt, windows-phone-8

It has been touted by Microsoft that Windows 8, Windows RT, and Windows Phone 8 will all have a "shared core" allowing for much faster development across the platforms.  Do we have any specific details as to what is in this "shared core?"

Comment: I suspect it has to do with MinWin, though my previous comment (which I deleted) didn't have an accurate source for my suspicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to the unified *Windows Runtime* application programming interface, which allows software developers to create applications which work and behave the same on windows phone, windows 8 and windows rt.

When you develop an app for one of these plattforms using the windows runtime, it usually also runs on the others without any modifications.